# Id none must be 15 characters

Tags: apex, standardcontroller, selectlist, selectoption

I am getting below error during execution time for below code in Apex page. I am unable to assign the value from here to standard controller. Can someone please help me?

**Apex Page**

```
 <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!AddressID}" id="Adrs" >
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!Addr}" ></apex:selectOptions>

      </apex:selectList>
```

**Apex Code snippet**

```
public List<SelectOption> getAddr() {


    String recordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('recordId');
    String Address;
    System.debug('Print--->'+recordId );
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('None','----Select----'));
    list<Address_vod__c> pv= [select name,id,Address_Line_2_vod__c, City_vod__c , State_vod__c , Zip_vod__c from Address_vod__c where Account_vod__r.name=: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('recordId')];
    for (Address_vod__c p:pv) {
    Address= p.Name+ ' , '+p.Address_line_2_vod__c+' , '+p.City_vod__c+' , '+p.State_vod__c+' , '+p.Zip_vod__c;
    Address= Address.replace('null', ' ');
    SelectOption entry = new SelectOption(Address,p.id);


    entry.setEscapeItem(false);
      options.add(entry);
    }

    return options;
  }
```

Comment: You didn't actually include the error text.

Comment: id None must be 15 characters
Also please find the screenshot

Comment: You didn't include a screenshot either. Have you looked over your post in its final form?

Comment: I am getting either subject error or the screesnhot error alternatively.

Comment: In debug log can't find the selected value AddressID

Comment: Dude...look at your post. There is no screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

The clue to your problem is in the error message:

> Id none must be 15 characters

so it looks like the error occurs when the first entry:

```
options.add(new SelectOption('None','----Select----'));
```

is chosen. For the other entries as kurunve suggests you should use `new SelectOption(p.id,Address)`.

The test below shows that a good way to go is to use an empty string that is automatically mapped to a null ID:

```
options.add(new SelectOption('','----Select----'));
```

Test code:

```
public class T {
    public SelectOption[] options {
        get {
            return new SelectOption[] {
                new SelectOption('', 'Empty'),
                new SelectOption('None', 'None')
                };
        }
    }
    public Id theId {get; set;}
    public PageReference doIt() {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'theId=' + theId));
        return null;
    }
}
<apex:page controller="T">
    <apex:pageMessages/>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!theId}">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
        <apex:commandButton value="Do It" action="{!doIt}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Why not just set the `SelectOption` value to `null`? Or can it not be done?

Comment: @AdrianLarson null can't be represented in HTML: an empty string would be closest and I think what Visualforce uses. Maybe the empty string is the better approach...

Comment: That's what I figured. Empty string would probably still cause issues but then you could at least use `String.isBlank` in your ternary. Cleaner imo.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Looks like the 15 character error is happening before the ternary so I've confirmed that an empty string is mapped automatically to a null ID and changed the answer to match.

Comment: Cool.  I learned something.   I had used Keith's original answer before

Answer (score 2):

If you check documentation about **SelectOption** class(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_selectoption.htm), you can see that first parameter in constructor is value, and second is label.

```
 SelectOption entry = new SelectOption(Address,p.id);
```

Instead of previous line, it should be like next:

```
 SelectOption entry = new SelectOption(p.id,Address);
```

It seems that your **AddressID** has Id type, but it is being stored as string, and that is place where error occurs. SF can not cast string to Id. To fix it, I would recommend swap params in SelectOption constructor, change **AddressID** to String type, and explicitly convert it to Id on demand where needed, with exceptions catching.

Comment: I have tried with that also. It gives same error. Even if I keep  SelectOption entry = new SelectOption(p.id,p.id); The result is same

Comment: @SFDC_Learner did you read about my second idea -- change type of AddressID to string?