# id Lead must be 15 characters

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, canvas, remote-objects

I'm updating a lead record using remote objects in visualforce page, and to update the record **i'm overriding the default update action with my custom controller method**. when i do that browser alerts/complains

> "id Lead must be 15 charecters"

This method is called via save button, from sfdc.canvas.publisher here is the javascript.

```
Sfdc.canvas.publisher.subscribe({
            name: "publisher.post",
            onData: function(e) {

                var picklist = document.getElementById("selid").value;

                var Comments = document.getElementById("id1").value;


                console.log('Inside the lead update');
                var ledid = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}";//18 digit Id
                var recid = ledid.substr(0, 15);//15 digit id
                console.log('substring --- > '+recid); //confirms it
                var mylead = new SObjectModel.Lead({
                    Id:recid 

                });

                mylead.set("Text__c", Comments);
                mylead.set("picklist__c", picklist);

                mylead.update(

                    function(error, records) {
                    if (error) {
                        alert(error.message);
                    } else {

                        Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({
                            name: "publisher.close",
                            payload: {
                                refresh: "true"
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

here is my remoteObject tags.

```
 <apex:remoteObjects >
 <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Lead" fields="Id,text__c,Picklist__c" update="!$RemoteAction.controller.updateLead}"/> 
 </apex:remoteObjects>
```

Comment: This sounds similar this post. Maybe it will help. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111289/id-none-must-be-15-characters

Comment: Is there a typo? You're using "ledid" and "leadid".  By the way, you can use the 18 character Id as well (the message predates the existence of 18-character ids, so is technically incorrect).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, but i just changed it for the purpose of posting otherwise, it would complain with a different message. By the way nice to meet you been following your posts from longtime.

Comment: @BrBarr they seems to have to problem with selectOption, and i removed my picklist from the update object and still throws the same error. thank you for taking time to comment.